# Terminal not taking cd command and going to home

Tags: macos, terminal

Terminal logs

```
Desktop cd
cd: no such file or directory: Users/rohanchoudhary

Desktop cd ../
rohanchoudhary cd ../
/Users cd ../
/
```

This says no Users/username directory exist.
How to fix this?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $HOME`?

Comment: Users/rohanchoudhary

Comment: Without a leading `/`? I don't know why it's not, but there must be a leading slash in the home path.

Comment: Getting this error while installing cocoapods: non-absolute home

Comment: That would point into the same direction. For some reason, your home path is not absolute. I don't know where this is set in macos, though.